# ¿Como filtrar imagenes explicitas cuando el usuario sube su foto de perfil en php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, filesystem

Pues aquí con otra duda.

Sabemos que cualquier persona por simple curiosidad o fastidiar, al momento de subir su foto de perfil en una pagina web, se le pudiera ocurrir subir imágenes al servidor con contenido explicito.

Es aquí donde me pregunto ¿como se haría un filtro para que detecte ese tipo de imágenes? que cuando se detecte que la imagen que ha subido al servidor es explicita, arroje un error de inserción o actualización, suponiendo que el entorno de desarrollo es con PHP, usando bd como mysql(si es que las imagenes son almacenadas en bd) o en caso contrario en archivos tipo $FILES.

He investigado un poco el tema y encontré funciones de PHP tales como ImageMagick, Gd que veo incluyen algunos trucos para el procesamiento de imágenes, encontré también plugins como Jquery filterizr pero creo que no ayuda mucho.

Espero que si alguien sabe un poco de este tema pueda orientarme.

Gracias a todos.

Comment: Hay una sola solución 100%  eficaz para esto: que alguien revise las imágenes que son subidas antes de publicarlas. Todo lo demás es confiar ese análisis a algoritmos y soluciones complicadas... y aún así  el ingenio humano es más grande que esas técnicas, encuentran vulnerabilidades para colarte imágenes.

Comment: moderación de contenidos es la forma, podes entrenar una AI pero suelen confundir fotos de dunas con desnudos =P

Comment: @A. Cedano hasta donde tengo entendido esa es la forma donde las aplicaciones y páginas web operan al día de hoy correcto. A mi me gustaría tener como lo menciona alo Malbarez una IA o alguna función por asi decirlo que me haga el trabajo del moderador, pero creo que eso ya conlleva un nivel de conocimiento mucho mas avanzado.

Comment: No dudo que exista ya algo parecido a lo que dice @alomalbarez ... Aunque soy escéptico en el sentido de que en cuestiones cómo estás delegues en una máquina. Aunque lo logres siempre habrá fallos restringiendo o permitiendo.

Comment: de mi experiencia con moderación de contenidos: podes usar una IA pero sólo como primer filtro para no atorar al/los moderadores con fotos de gatos, si la comunidad es lo suficientemente grande podes implementar una moderación de pares, mirosoft y google ofrecen servicios (freemium) para identificar fotos por ejemplo : https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/filtering-inappropriate-content-with-the-cloud-vision-api

Comment: mas que nada es una cuestión de que "imagenes explícitas" varía de cultura en cultura y de ámbito en ámbito, el ejemplo mas claro son imágenes de procedimientos médicos

Comment: como siempre no encuentro la doc del api de bing (microsoft), pero un punto de partida es https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/bing-visual-search/

Answer (score 2):

Un modelo de Machine Learning puede tomar semanas en entrenar. Básicamente tienes que alimentarlo con (al menos) medio millón de imágenes diciéndole cual es NSFW y cual es segura. Con eso la máquina podría predecir si una nueva imagen es o no es NSFW. Pero este tipo de algoritmos de Machine Learning tienen una curva de aprendizaje empinada y necesitas un servidor poderoso para entrenar.

Podrías usar un servicio web. Por ejemplo, [VRate](https://vrate.net/#!/pricing) te permite 7500 llamadas **gratuitas** al  al mes. En el fondo la persona sube la imagen, tú la disponibilizas en una URL pública (tal que VRate pueda verla) envías un llamado al API de VRate con la url de la imagen y ésta te dice si es NSFW.

Usando PHP, copias la imagen a una URL que no es la que se despliega al resto de los usuarios. Por ejemplo, si la URL normal es:

```
http://www.noctis.com/avatar/mi_avatar.png
```

Tú la disponibilizas primero en

```
http://www.noctis.com/pendiente/mi_avatar.png
```

Luego mandas un request al endpoint [mediarating](https://market.mashape.com/vrate/detect-nudity-pornography-and-obscene-content-in-images#mediarating) usando (por ejemplo) [Unirest](http://unirest.io/) con un request de tipo  [application/json](http://unirest.io/php.html#user-content-json-requests-applicationjson):

```
$headers = [
    "X-Mashape-Key" => "YOUR_API_KEY",
    "Accept" => "application/json"
  ];

$data = ["payload":"http://www.noctis.com/pendiente/mi_avatar.png"];

$body = Unirest\Request\Body::json($data);

$response = Unirest\Request::post(
     'https://vrate.p.mashape.com/mediarating',
     $headers,
     $data
);
```

La respuesta es un JSON de la forma:

```
{
  "RatingCode": "V01",
  "RatingDescription": "Safe, Ok",
  "Confidence": "High"
}
```

Otra alternativa (pero que permite sólo 1000 llamados gratis al mes) es [DeepAI](https://deepai.org/api-docs/#nudity-detection).

De nuevo usando [Unirest](http://unirest.io/) pero con un request de tipo [application/x-www-form-urlencoded](http://unirest.io/php.html#user-content-form-requests-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded) que es lo que espera DeepAI:

```
$headers = [ 'Api-Key': 'YOUR_API_KEY'];
$data = ['image' => 'http://www.noctis.com/pendiente/mi_avatar.png'];

$body = Unirest\Request\Body::form($data);

$response = Unirest\Request::post(
     'https://api.deepai.org/api/nsfw-detector', 
     $headers, 
     $body
);
```

La respuesta será un JSON de la forma:

```
{
  "nsfw_score": 0.041
}
```

Si la respuesta es satisfactoria, copias la imagen a

```
 http://www.noctis.com/pendiente/mi_avatar.png
```

Y todo sigue su curso. En caso contrario, despliegas un mensaje de error, le pides al usuario que suba otra foto y, por debajo, borras la imagen del servidor que era visible en

```
http://www.noctis.com/pendiente/mi_avatar.png
```